# Install LVM on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, iso, lvm, setup, alternate

I want to setup an Ubuntu server with LVM. I installed Ubuntu using ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso because I believe that the "alternate" disc must be used to install with LVM. However it created an Ubuntu desktop for me. Where did I go wrong? Should I use the server iso or is there someplace in the alternate iso where I can change a setting to not install the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no real difference if you use the alternate or server iso.
IMHO is the only difference between desktop and server installation the set of installed packages. Since 2011(?) the special server kernel is dropped.

To install an ubuntu system with LVM you have to take attention at the partitioning step in the installer. This is the point where you introduce your LVM configuration selecting *pysical volumnes*, *volumne group* and *logical volumnes*.

After creating this assets you continue in the usual way assigning the *logical volumnes* in the same way as a traditional partition to a mountpoint.

As a little trick it can be useful to switch from the installer to the shell and invoke the necessary LVM commands inside the shell (e.g. copy&paste from your note-book).

#### Recomendation

No Server without underlying **mdraid** below the LVM layer.
This will be a significant improvement to the data security (raid 1,5 or 6 assumed).

Comment: I'm very confused because I've seen numerous places that state I must use the alternate disc to do an LVM install, but it seems that's wrong. Here are a few: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36568/what-is-logical-volume-management-and-how-do-you-enable-it-in-ubuntu/, http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LVMOnRaid, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall. I guess those docs are all just old? Why does the releases page mention LVM under the alternate install CD if you can do it with the server ISO?

Comment: The differences between the iso are mainly the set of hardware drivers available in the image and some differences in the installer modules.